# Can't access Ubuntu 15.04 Power Settings screen

Tags: 15.04, power-management

Opening Settings works, all the sub-categories work, but if I go to System Settings and then click the Power icon, the Settings app hangs and has to be force-quit. No crash report is available--it says there's a crash report error. This also happens if I access the link to Power Settings from the Security screen.

I'm not aware of making any changes that might have caused this...

Any ideas?